# Cannot post on users friend's wall, I receive "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I cannot send post on a user's friend's wall, but I can post on the user's wall itself.
I have access to publish_steam of the user!
The userId is the friend's ID,

```
   try {
        $publishStream = $this->api("/$userId/feed", 'post', array(
            'message' => $message,
            'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken()
                ));
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

I receive "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" , OAuthException

However, I can write on to the user's wall itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [recent changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/), the only way to post on user's friend's wall is to use [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)